# How can Spring AOP matches annotation on interface method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-aop

I use mybatis. My question is how can Spring AOP matches annotation on interface method? Because I want to put some param in annotation and then handle them in afterReturning method.

my annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CacheClear {
    String key() default "";
}
```

in mapper class:

```
@CacheClear
List<BizInst> selectAllBizInsts();
```

and in my aspect:

when use "execute..." it works

```
@AfterReturning("execution(public * com.dao.*.select*(..))")
public void doAfterReturning(){
    System.out.println("after returning");
}
```

but when use "@annotation(...)" it doesn't work

```
@AfterReturning("@annotation(com.annotation.CacheClear)")
public void doAfterReturning(){
    System.out.println("after returning");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that for selecting your public dao methods annotated with CacheClear annotation:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.yourPackage.CacheClear * *(..))")
public void methodAnnotatedWithCacheClear( ) {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.dao.*.select*(..))")
public void publicDAOMethod() {}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "methodAnnotatedWithCacheClear() && publicDAOMethod()", returning = "result")
public void doStuff(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
```